# ¿Como elimino un archivo a pesar de estar siendo usado por un proceso?

Tags: python, telegram

Estoy desarrollando un bot para telegram, una de sus funciones es la posibilidad de compartir un video de youtube y descargarlo.

Usando una librería llamada "PAFY" [documentación aquí](https://pythonhosted.org/pafy/#Pafy.Pafy.title) he conseguido hacer posible descargar un video de YouTube a partir de un link y mandarlo mediante Telegram. Mi problema es el siguiente-->

-Cuando se descarga el video y se manda al usuario, dicho video se descarga en mi ordenador, en mi carpeta donde está alojado mi bot.py. Mi idea es cuando se mande el video, eliminarlo con os.remove. El problema de esto es que me lanza la exception `[WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'The Real Pencorder.mp4'`

```
    if pattern.match(message.text):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Es un link de youtube valido")
    vid = pafy.new(message.text)
    s = vid.getbest()
    video = open(s.download(), 'rb')
    bot.send_video(message.chat.id,video)
    path = vid.title+'.mp4'
    os.remove(path)
```

Mi pregunta es. ¿Como consigo eliminar dicho video aun habiendo procesos que lo usan? He de decir que uso Windows 10

Comment: Cierra el archivo antes, no debes nunca usar `open` sin el manejador de contexto (`with`) o cerrando explícitamente el archivo con `close`, aunque eventualemnte el GC va a terminar cerrandolo cuando el programa termine es una mala práctica siempre.  En principio, debes hacer `video.close()` antes de `os.remove`.

Comment: Vaya! Ahora funciona, vaya fallito mas tonto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema ha sido respondido en los comentarios. Me saltaba la excepción

```
[WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'The Real Pencorder.mp4'
```

Porque mi programa no habia cerrado el flujo con dicho video. Usando "Video.close()" se resuelve el problema y se puede borrar el video.